# Starting and Pausing with a Countdown Timer in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
 import tkinter as tk

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Pomodoro Timer")

        self.state = False
        self.minutes = 25
        self.seconds = 0

        self.display = tk.Label(master, height=10, width=10, textvariable="")
        self.display.config(text="00:00")
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Green", activebackground="Dark Green", text="Start", width=8, height=4, command=self.start())
        self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.pause_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Red", activebackground="Dark Red", text="Pause", width=8, height=4, command=self.pause())
        self.pause_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.countdown()

    def countdown(self):
        """Displays a clock starting at min:sec to 00:00, ex: 25:00 -> 00:00"""
        mins = self.minutes
        secs = self.seconds

        if self.state == True:
            if secs < 10:
                if mins < 10:
                    self.display.config(text="0%d : 0%d" % (mins, secs))
                else:
                    self.display.config(text="%d : 0%d" % (mins, secs))
            else:
                if mins < 10:
                    self.display.config(text="0%d : %d" % (mins, secs))
                else:
                    self.display.config(text="%d : %d" % (mins, secs))

            if (mins == 0) and (secs == 0):
                self.display.config(text="Done!")
            else:
                if secs == 0:
                    mins -= 1
                    secs = 59
                else:
                    secs -= 1

                self.master.after(1000, self.countdown())

        elif self.state == False:
            self.master.after(100, self.countdown())

    def start(self):
        if self.state == False:
            self.state = True

    def pause(self):
        if self.state == True:
            self.state = False



root = tk.Tk()
my_timer = Timer(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Pretty new to Python in general, am attempting to make what is essentially a simple countdown timer with start and pause abilities.

What I thought would work would be to call the countdown function right when the window was initiated, having it continually check the "state" of the window through a recursive call. When the "state" is False the countdown function would skip over the "timer" portion of the countdown function and call it again to see if the "state" had changed.

When the user clicks the start button the "state" would change to True and the countdown function would now see the "state" had changed and then would begin actually counting down.

Then when the user clicked the pause button the "state" would change to False again and the countdown function would again skip over the "timer" portion of the function and simply call it again.

Issue I keep running into is something like:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Not sure how I can get around this error with the implementation I currently have.

**Edit:**

So changing self.countdown() to self.countdown in both instances (not under init) does fix the error, but now the function simply is "stuck". The desired window appears, but none of the buttons appear to be working.

Comment: Does it give you a line number? Also, you have a typo in your `start` definition, `self.state == True` needs to be `self.state = True`.

Comment: Tk's `after()` method takes a reference to a function to be called later, `self.countdown` perhaps.  You're passing `self.countdown()`, which is the result of calling the function *right now* (and is `None`, because the function does not explicitly return another value).

Comment: So changing self.countdown() to self.countdown in both instances (not under __init__) does fix the error, but now the function simply is "stuck". The desired window appears, but none of the buttons appear to be working.

Comment: `comman=` like `after()` and `bind()` needs function name without `()`

Comment: inside `countdown()` you can't use `mins = self.minutes`, `secs = self.seconds` because it resets values to 25:00. Set it in `start()`. But you have to use `self.min`, `self.sec` to keep values between executons of `countdown()` by `after()`

Comment: There are many questions on this site related to timers and clocks with tkinter. Did you read through them before posting? I don't see any evidence of any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=`, `after()` and `bind()` needs function name without `()` (sometimes it is called `callback`)

`countdown()` is executed by `after()` like any other function (but later), and it means:

1. `countdown()` recreates all local values in every execution so they don't keep values. You have to use `self.mins` and `self.secs` to keep values.
2. inside `countdown()` you can't use

   ```
   mins = self.minutes
   secs = self.seconds
   ```

   because it resets time to 25:00 in every execution. You have to set it in `start()`

Working code

```
import tkinter as tk

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Pomodoro Timer")

        self.state = False
        self.minutes = 25
        self.seconds = 0

        self.mins = 25
        self.secs = 0

        self.display = tk.Label(master, height=10, width=10, textvariable="")
        self.display.config(text="00:00")
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Green", activebackground="Dark Green", text="Start", width=8, height=4, command=self.start)
        self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.pause_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Red", activebackground="Dark Red", text="Pause", width=8, height=4, command=self.pause)
        self.pause_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.countdown()

    def countdown(self):
        """Displays a clock starting at min:sec to 00:00, ex: 25:00 -> 00:00"""

        if self.state == True:
            if self.secs < 10:
                if self.mins < 10:
                    self.display.config(text="0%d : 0%d" % (self.mins, self.secs))
                else:
                    self.display.config(text="%d : 0%d" % (self.mins, self.secs))
            else:
                if self.mins < 10:
                    self.display.config(text="0%d : %d" % (self.mins, self.secs))
                else:
                    self.display.config(text="%d : %d" % (self.mins, self.secs))

            if (self.mins == 0) and (self.secs == 0):
                self.display.config(text="Done!")
            else:
                if self.secs == 0:
                    self.mins -= 1
                    self.secs = 59
                else:
                    self.secs -= 1

                self.master.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            self.master.after(100, self.countdown)

    def start(self):
        if self.state == False:
            self.state = True
            self.mins = self.minutes
            self.secs = self.seconds

    def pause(self):
        if self.state == True:
            self.state = False



root = tk.Tk()
my_timer = Timer(root)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** as @EL3PHANTEN pointed out you can use string formatting to make it shorter:

```
text='{:02} : {:02}'.format(self.mins,self.secs)
```

or

```
text="%02d : %02d" % (self.mins,self.secs)
```

I also moved line `self.countdown()` from `__init__` to `start()` and now I don't need second `after()` inside `countdown()`.

I also set `self.state = False` when it displays `Done!`

```
import tkinter as tk

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Pomodoro Timer")

        self.state = False
        self.minutes = 25
        self.seconds = 0

        self.mins = 25
        self.secs = 0

        self.display = tk.Label(master, height=10, width=10, textvariable="")
        self.display.config(text="00:00")
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Green", activebackground="Dark Green", text="Start", width=8, height=4, command=self.start)
        self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.pause_button = tk.Button(master, bg="Red", activebackground="Dark Red", text="Pause", width=8, height=4, command=self.pause)
        self.pause_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def countdown(self):
        """Displays a clock starting at min:sec to 00:00, ex: 25:00 -> 00:00"""

        if self.state == True:

            if (self.mins == 0) and (self.secs == 0):
                self.display.config(text="Done!")
                self.state = False
            else:
                self.display.config(text="%02d:%02d" % (self.mins, self.secs))

                if self.secs == 0:
                    self.mins -= 1
                    self.secs = 59
                else:
                    self.secs -= 1

                self.master.after(1000, self.countdown)

    def start(self):
        if self.state == False:
            self.state = True
            self.mins = self.minutes
            self.secs = self.seconds
            self.countdown()

    def pause(self):
        if self.state == True:
            self.state = False



root = tk.Tk()
my_timer = Timer(root)

root.mainloop()
"{:02} : {:02}".format(10, 0)
```

Comment: I would replace all that `if else` on the display of the clock with `(text='{:02} : {:02}'.format(self.mins,self.secs))` Then you always have 2 digits on each of those

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You gave tremendously helpful advice, the formatting input @EL3PHANTEN gave was also a great help!